# Java - File manipulation

Tags: java, logic

I have some content in an input file a.txt as

```
Line 1 : "abcdefghijk001mnopqr hellohello"
Line 2 : "qwertyuiop002asdfgh welcometologic"
Line 3 : "iamworkingherefromnowhere002yes somethingsomething"
Line 4 : "thiswillbesolved001here ithink"
```

I have to read the a.txt file and write it to two separate files. ie., lines having 001 should be written to output1.txt and lines having 002 should be written to output2.txt

Can someone help me on this with a logic in Java programming.

Thanks,
Naren

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is good. Google and try something and post your code if any error or logical mistakes etc to get resolve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "a.txt" ));
String line;
while(( line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
    if( line.contains( "001" )) sendToFile001( line );
    if( line.contains( "002" )) sendToFile002( line );
}
br.close();
```

The method sendToFile001() and sendToFile002() write  the parameter line as follow:

```
ps001.println( line );
```

with ps001 and ps002 of type PrintStream, opened before (in a constructor?)

Comment: If i go with this, i am not writing all the lines, only the last iterated line gets written

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example for [Reading and writing text files using Java](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) and checking conditions do the following

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //process each line in some way
    if(line.contains("001") {
     fileWriter1.write(line);  
    } else if (line.contains("002") ) {
     fileWriter2.write(line);    
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code complete.

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jfile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 *
 * @author andy
 */
public class JFile {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    static File master = null,
                m1     = null, // file output with "001"
                m2     = null; // file output with "002"

    static FileWriter fw1,
                      fw2;

    static FileReader fr = null;
    static BufferedReader br = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {

         String root = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/files/";

         master = new File ( root + "master.txt" );
         m1     = new File ( root + "m1.txt");
         m2     = new File ( root + "m2.txt");

         fw1     = new FileWriter(m1, true);
         fw2     = new FileWriter(m2, true);


         fr = new FileReader (master);
         br = new BufferedReader(fr);

         String line;
         while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
         {
             if(line.contains("001")) 
             {               
                 fw1.write(line + "\n");

             } else if (line.contains("002"))
             {
                 fw2.write(line + "\n");

             }
         }

         fw1.close();
         fw2.close();
         br.close();
    }

}
```

*Project Netbeans* : http://www.mediafire.com/?yjdtxj2gh785cyd

Comment: What if a line contains 001 AND 002? (remove else between ifs)